# Installing Linux Kali on Lenovo G50

Tags: system-installation, kali-linux

I recently bought a Lenovo g50 to run kali on. I installed kali from a usb flash drive because of the new bios. Everything went well so far, but i had to install it without internet connection since my ethernet is matched with my mac adress and id have to ask the network guy to refresh for the lenovo mac to be accepted, and then move back again, which is a pain. When i started up, the gui wouldnt start up as you can see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doRnfA0r1TM) , sorry for the quality.

After that i tried logging in as root by pressing ALT+F4 which worked and i got root access. I tried to `start gdm3` but it failed showing no error. I then tried to run `startx` but it wasnt installed. I connected the ethernet cable after spoofing my mac address with macchanger to be the same with my desktop.
This worked and i got internet access, but i when i tried to run `apt-get install xorg` i was told that the package could not be found, and i got the same response for many other very well known packages. 
I think during the instalation apt was not set well, is there a way to do that now that i can connect to the internet so that i can finaly install xorg and maybe get the gui to work.

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select the default display manager.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` not `gdm`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was with gdm not finding a screen because of some bios bug. A bios update solved the problem.